# Capture semantics when assigning a function to a block in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

I'm wondering about what it means when you assign a function to a block in Swift in terms of memory management (i.e. I want to avoid a retain cycle).

For example, say I have a button with the following definition:

```
class Button {
  var wasTapped: () -> Void
}
```

And I use it in a view controller as so:

```
class ViewController {
  let button: Button

  func setUpButtonHandler() {
    button.wasTapped = ...
  }

  func buttonWasTapped() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

My question is about the assignment of `button.wasTapped = ...`.

Obviously if I set it like so:

```
button.wasTapped = { self.buttonWasTapped() }
```

I just created a retain cycle: ViewController -> Button -> ViewController.

However, Swift allows me to do this instead:

```
button.wasTapped = buttonWasTapped
```

Is it safe to do this? (I.e. would this prevent a retain cycle?)

Answer (score 4):

That would still create a retain cycle.

A good way to think about it is to realize that anytime you see:

```
button.wasTapped = buttonWasTapped
```

It's just shorthand for:

```
button.wasTapped = { self.buttonWasTapped() }
```

Which obviously creates a retain cycle, as the explicit use of `self` clearly shows.

**It's confusing because the retain cycle is obvious in the second version, but not the first.**

Unfortunately, this means you'll need to stick to the more verbose (and retain-cycle avoiding):

```
button.wasTapped = { [weak self] in self?.buttonWasTapped() }
```

---

You can verify this behavior with this playground:

```
class Button {
  var wasTapped: () -> Void

  init() {
    wasTapped = {}
  }
}

class ViewController {
  let button: Button

  func setUpButtonHandler() {
    //button.wasTapped = { [weak self] in self?.buttonWasTapped() } // no retain cycle
    //button.wasTapped = { self.buttonWasTapped() } // retain cycle
    //button.wasTapped = buttonWasTapped // retain cycle
  }

  func buttonWasTapped() {
    print("tapped!")
  }

  init() {
    button = Button()
    setUpButtonHandler()
  }

  deinit {
    print("deinit")
  }
}

func test() {
  let vc = ViewController()
  vc.button.wasTapped()
}

test()
```

---

**Update:** more details can be found here: [Function references in Swift and retain cycles](http://blog.xebia.com/function-references-in-swift-and-retain-cycles/)